# Retrieving a Geocoding Result from ArcGIS Online World Geocoder

Tags: arcgis-10.2, geocoding, geocoding-service

I ran the World geocoder service through AGOL on a lot of points (I forgot how expensive it is - dumb dumb mistake, alas!). Worse still, the ArcMap Desktop mxd where I had the results open as I was going through the Tied records and manually matching them, died in the middle of the process, before I saved the mxd. Ack!!! I am trying to figure out if I can get those geocoder results back into Desktop somehow, but I don’t know where to look for them. They better be retrievable, given how much they cost me! I have a standalone Standard ArcGIS Desktop license, and an Organization ArcGIS Online account.

Answer (score 1):

For your MXD, and in the geoprocessing process you have to define the source and destination where the results are stored. So there is someplace on your machine a gdb (usually in your My Documents) where the default.gdb resides.

Comment: Thank you! I did check in my Default gdb, I saw no geocoding results there. The problem is that they were generated by ArcGIS Online, so I wonder if it's possible the temporary file was remotely stored. I found nothing in my ArcGIS Online Content or MyESRI Reports either, sadly.

Comment: You should be able to go to your "Results" view under the geoprocessing menu and see where the last run tasks where processed and stored.

Comment: Good idea! Since that mxd died without being saved, I can't see those Results anymore. A different mxd is using the Default gdb for Scratch Workspace. I don't see any geocoding results in there, sadly. Thank you for thinking this through with me!